# MPI receiving just zeros at message size of 2^16

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

For the physics code I am working on we recently ran into a problem where when we increase our problem size so that some mpi messages are above 2^16 (including the sizeof() ) those messages are received as just 0's. For messages prior to that size the communication happens correctly.

Google-ing the problem has led me to believe that the problem may be due to the 'eager limit': see [this](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/what-is-an-mpi-eager-limit/) and [this](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/eager-limits-part-2/).

Our current communication pattern is one where we post isend's and then continue with our execution otherwise. On the receiving side we do iprobes after pieces of our execution finish, looping through all active iprobes and recv if the message exists.

My attempts so far at reproducing this problem minimally haven't worked yet:

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    boost::mpi::environment env;
    boost::mpi::communicator world;
    int length = 16384;

    std::vector<double> send(length, 5.0);
    std::vector<double> noise(length, 10.0);
    std::vector<double> receive(length);

    std::cout<<"Sent: "<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    for( std::vector<double>::const_iterator i = send.begin(); i != send.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<*i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<send.size()*sizeof(int)<<std::endl;
    boost::mpi::request req = world.isend(0, 1, &send[0], send.size());

    boost::optional<boost::mpi::status> msg = world.iprobe();
    while(!msg){
        msg = world.iprobe();
    }
    boost::mpi::request noisereq = world.isend(0,1, &noise[0], noise.size());
    world.recv(0, 1, &receive[0], length);
    std::cout<<"Received: "<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    for( std::vector<double>::const_iterator i = receive.begin(); i != receive.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<*i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    req.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Which, unfortunately for me, compiles and runs without the (in this case) desired effect of just receiving 0's. Posting the actual code is not an option. I will continue trying to edit the above code to try and observe the failure by bringing the code closer to what we are doing, but the basic idea is already as above.

We think that changing the first iprobe to an irecv and then the loop to an test of the status object might help in solving the issue, but we do not understand what the issue is enough to be sure.

Why does passing the eager limit cause us to receive 0's? 
Why doesn't it fail prior to that point? 
Why does it receive 0's as opposed to crashing if we are doing something wrong? 
How do we get our code working?

The problem was first observed on Open MPI, it also occurs with MPICH and MVAPICH2.

---

Since I can't answer this but I did discover the answer:

This exercise in bringing the above closer to what we are doing in the code was really useful and uncovered the error and why the eager limit mattered. This code now behaves close to the same as our code:

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp> 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename numeric>
void cout_vector(std::vector<numeric> & v)
{
    for( typename std::vector<numeric>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
        std::cout<<*i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
boost::mpi::request Send( const int destID, const int tag, const std::vector<T>& send, boost::mpi::communicator& world)
{
    std::vector<T> buffer(send);
    boost::mpi::request req = world.isend(destID, tag, &buffer[0], buffer.size() );
    return req;
}

template<typename T>
void Receive(const int srcID, const int tag, T& recieve, boost::mpi::communicator& world)
{
    world.recv(srcID, tag, &recieve[0], recieve.size());
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    boost::mpi::environment env;
    boost::mpi::communicator world;
    int length = 16384;

    std::vector<double> send(length, 5.0);
    std::vector<double> noise(length, 0.0);
    std::vector<double> receive(length);

    std::cout<<"Sent: "<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    cout_vector(send);
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<send.size()*sizeof(int)<<std::endl;

    boost::mpi::request req = Send(0, 1, send, world);

    boost::optional<boost::mpi::status> msg = world.iprobe();
    while(!msg){
        msg = world.iprobe();
    }

    boost::mpi::request noisereq = Send(0,2, noise, world);
    Receive(0, 1, receive, world);
    std::cout<<"Received: "<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    cout_vector(receive);
    req.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

The reason being that the send buffer is not persistent enough: below the eager limit everything that is placed in that buffer is automatically sent and the non-persistence of the buffer does not matter, above the eager limit the buffer gets corrupted (destroyed or reused) prior to the receive happening, as the send doesn't happen then.

Changing to an irecv and posting it first, getting rid of the iprobe and instead testing the status of the irecv does solve the problem. The communication happens as soon as the isend is posted.

Ensuring the persistence of the buffer also fixes the problem.

Comment: Are you at liberty to say which MPI implementation you're using?  Does it happen on more than one?

Comment: I thought about editing that in, I guess I should have; I have it happening with Open MPI. On my own machine I have Open Mpi 1.6.5.

Comment: And this behavior is in accordance with the standard. You may not change or destroy the buffer before asynchronous request has completed. Completion of `isend` means just that the MPI implementation has taken care of the data.

Comment: As already stated by @DmitriChubarov, once you post a non-blocking send, the data buffer should not be modified until the request has been waited on or tested and the test shows that the operation has completed.